# $.append before changing $.prop('name')? (name attribute not showing in Chrome "Elements")

Tags: javascript, jquery, constructor, append, name-attribute

I'm dynamically constructing elements for recurring html.

I'm creating a `display:table`, and all seems to be going well, but when I change the `name` of an element before it's been `$.append()`ed, it doesn't show up in Chrome "Elements" and cannot be later selected by jQuery; however, before `$.append()`ing, the `$.prop('name')` can be `alert()`ed.

Should the dynamically constructed element be `$.append()`ed before changing `$.prop('name')`?

Code sample:

```
$.fn.appendSingleRecordInsert = function(paramaterObject) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $appendDiv = $('<div/>')
        ...
        $.each(paramaterObject.rows, function(rowKey, rowValue){
            var $rowDiv = $('<div/>');
            $.each(rowValue.columns, function(columnKey, columnValue){
                var $columnDiv = $('<div/>');
                if(typeof columnValue.name !== 'undefined'{
                    $columnDiv.prop('name', columnValue.name);
                }
                ...
                $rowDiv.append($columnDiv);
            })
            $appendDiv.append($rowDiv);
        });
        $(this)[paramaterObject.domInsertMethod]($appendDiv);
    });
```

Comment: The element is visible and shows up in inspect element but just has the wrong name?  Have you tried `attr` instead?

Comment: @JamesMontagne yep, all the rest of the code around it works as expected.  thought `attr` was "bad" ;))  will try!....`UPDATE`: it worked!  want to expand to answer?  have any idea why?

Comment: In my head at least, `attr` makes more sense when working with an element which has not been added to the dom.

Comment: @JamesMontagne i def learned something new today, ty!  do you mind expanding to answer for later readers?

Comment: checkign on a few things.  Posted an answer, will likely update with a bit more detail.

Comment: When you say it "can't be selected by jQuery", do you mean you are trying to select with the attribute selector?  `$("div[name=...`?

Comment: @JamesMontagne yep, but it can now because of your fix.  i changed it to a `class` to be more correct as you and Bergi recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `attr` instead of `prop`.  The "attribute selector" selects based on attributes, not properties.  In order to do something like `$("div[name=...` you must set the attribute, not the property.

It should be noted though that `name` is not a valid attribute on a `div`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.name) is not applicable to `<div>` elements - they have no `name` attribute. Because of that, the property change you're doing will not be reflected in the attribute values (DOM inspector).

You should use an id or a class instead if you need a selector.